# Taxonomy Menu & Hierarchy Trees

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

So I tried this tutorial on [Taxonomy Menu and Menu Block](http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-add-block-menu-tags-or-other-taxonomy-terms-drupal-site). Now I set up the block to go in the header showing only 1 level deep.

My goal is to click on that 1 level deep link and generate a second menu showing the hierarchy. Instead I get a generic template that displays all posts of the parent taxonomy.

So, ideally:

1. [Header Menu Item] > Goes to hierarchy tree

   - Sub category 1 > Goes to hierarchy tree

     - Nodes of sub category 1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Taxonomy Split](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_split), Drupal 6 only at the moment.

> if you have a vocabulary in the form of a tree, eg it has terms within terms with nodes attached to them.
>
> It will place all the first level terms in a block and when a term is clicked displays the tree below that term in another block.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used [DHTML menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu) for a similar need. The module allows several behaviors - I used the javascript-based tree browsing. The tree also auto-expands to show reveal the active term, but as far as I recall you'll need [Taxonomy Menu Trails](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_trails) for that to work.